# Why this two dynamical Systems are not isomorphic?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Given two dynamical Systems on [0,1) with the Borel $\sigma-Algebra$ and the Lebesgue measure l.

$T_a (x) = x + a$ mod1
$T_2 (x) = 2x$ mod1.
 Show that this two systems are not isomorphic for any choice of a:

We've already showed, that $T_2$ is ergodic. $T_a$ is just ergodic if a is irrational. Now I still have to show, that the two systems are not isomorphic for irrational a. Don't know how to do this? I first tried to assume that there is an isomorphism and to construct a contradiction…I failed. What are other invariants of dynamical systems under isomorphism besides ergodicity? may someone help me?

Comment: We have this definition of a dynamical system: For a set X, a $\sigma-algebra$ B on X, a measure l on B and a measure preventing map T: X -> X (X,B,l,T) is called a dynamic system.

Comment: A very useful invariant for dynamical systems is the Kolmogorv-Sinai entropy, have you heard of this?

Comment: I have an idea how to show it now maybe: T_a is invertible and I guess that maybe T_2 is not invertible and that this is an invariant.

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: Hello Sofia, first thank you for your answer. No I haven't I just started doing ergodic theory last week so I guess the exercise can be solved with very "easy" stuff. We showed in the lecture that the 2nd system is isomorphic to the "left-shift" of a sequence of {0,1} indicated by the natural numbers and I guess that this system is not invertible, while the first is invertible (because the Lebegue measure is invariant under translations)

Comment: Okay nice thank you, I'll try to write it down first and then see if I have questions left =)

Comment: Okay: $T_a$ is invertible, it is easy to check that $T_{-a}$ is the inverse. But $T_2$ is not invertible, since the inverse image of x is $\{\frac{x}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\}$. (Question: Is this correct for dynamical Systems?: T satisfies l(T(A))=l(A) for all A in B <=> T is invertible??)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that invertibility is an invariant after all, as anything may happen on a set of measure zero. But if you can show that there is no measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1)$ such that $T_2$ is invertible on $A$ and $A$ is of full measure, I belive you are done.

Comment: @Sofia In this example every point has preiamge of two points, so such set $A$ you said about can not be found. So I think crank's method can work.

Comment: Another useful invariant would be strong or weak mixing.

Comment: Or maybe use the simplex of all measures (which is big for the doubling map, but a singleton for the irrational rotation).

Comment: I hope that invertibilness is an invariant of dynamical systems, since this was the only property of dynamical systems we spoke about in the lecture (besides ergodicity). I will open a new thread to discuss this.Thx all

Comment: @MHS Unique ergodicity would be an invariant of the *topological* dynamical system, not the measure-theoretic one. Jewett-Krieger Theorem tells us that every measure-theoretic dynamical system on a standard probability space has a uniquely ergodic topological model.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities here. I'm gonna use $m$ to refer to Lebesgue measure on the unit interval $[0 , 1)$. These are roughly in ascending order of "sophistication".

(1) The map $T_a$ is invertible, meaning that it not only has the property that $m(A) = m \left(T_a^{-1} A \right)$ for all measurable $A$, which is the definition of a measure-preserving map, but also $m(A) = m(T_a A)$ for all measurable $A$. The map $T_2$ does not have this property. Note that it's not quite enough to just observe that $T_2$ is not invertible as a map from $[0, 1)$ to itself. As others remarked, a lot can happen on a null set.

(2) The map $T_2$ is weakly mixing, strongly mixing, and even Bernoulli. The map $T_a$ is none of these.

(3) The map $T_2$ has positive entropy, whereas $T_a$ has entropy $0$.